# MYSQL stored procedure for update variables are 0

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure in a MYSQL database. The stored procedure gets lon,lat and than I'm doing an update on a different database and table.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS annuals.updateSalesFlorida;
CREATE DEFINER=`dddd`@`%` PROCEDURE `updateSales`(propertyId int)
BEGIN

   DECLARE lat   FLOAT;
    DECLARE lon FLOAT;


  SELECT  SitusLongitude,SitusLatitude
  INTO lon,lat
  FROM annuals.florida
  WHERE PropertyID=propertyId
  LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE;

  UPDATE sales.florida
  SET
    `SitusLongitude` = lon,
    `SitusLatitude` = lat
  WHERE PROPERTYUNIQUEID=propertyId;

END;
```

Every time I run the stored procedure the `SitusLongitude` and `SitusLatitude` columns are 0. I know for a fact that the previous selected `SitusLongitude` and `SitusLatitude` have actual values in there. For some reason the variables are not being set in lat,lon.  Any idea what I'm dong wrong?

Comment: There could be any number of mistakes. You're not showing us your tables, your data, your input or your output, yet you want us to accept your assertion that your code is simultaneously correct and incorrect. Please provide a [mcve], ideally using [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Comment: Why are you doing this as two queries? Just do a single `UPDATE` query with a `JOIN`.

Comment: Not sure how, I thought the above would be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the procedure parameter has the same name as a column in the tables. When you refer to `propertyid` in the queries, it uses the column, not the parameter. Column and variable names are case-insensitive, so it doesn't matter that you spelled one of them `PropertyID` and the other `propertyId`.

Use a different name for the parameter, e.g. `p_propertyId`

Also, there's no need for two queries, you can do it in one with a `JOIN`.

```
UPDATE sales.florida AS s
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM annuals.florida
    WHERE propertyId = p_propertyId
    LIMIT 1) AS a
SET s.SitusLongitude = a.SitusLongitude, s.SitusLatitude = a.SitusLatitude
WHERE s.PROPERTYUNIQUEID = p_propertyId
```

Note that using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` means that the row that's selected will be unpredictable.